# In Azure DocumentDB some queries don't work

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I used Azure DocumentDB to store some Key-Values pairs. This is the structure of the document I used

```
{
    "Key": "Deleted",
    "Value": {
      "email": "abc@cdf.com"
    }
}
```

When i write DocumentDB query like this,

```
SELECT C.Value FROM C
```

This query does not work. Here is the error message I get.

```
Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'Value'.
```

But this query works fine,

```
SELECT C.Key FROM C
```

I understand '`Value`' should be a keyword in azure documentdb. How can i query it?

Comment: Did you tried to quote that identifier? Something like `SELECT C.'Value' FROM C` or `SELECT C."Value" FROM C`

Comment: did you try select value c.value ?

Comment: @MilanTomeš Yes i did try both. No progess!.

Comment: @Aravind I just tried it. Still the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Value is a keyword in DocumentDB syntax so this is why you get an error. See Value keyword in this article [DocumentDB syntax](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/) - The VALUE keyword provides a way to return JSON value.

To get around this you can query it the way Yannick has said i.e.

```
SELECT C['Value'] FROM C
```

Answer (score 5):

Because your documents are stored as JSON, you can access them as follows:

```
SELECT C['Value'] FROM C
```

This will result in:

```
[
  {
    "Value": {
      "email": "abc@cdf.com"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

In DocumentDB query grammar, the syntax < collection_expresion >.property_name is exactly same as < collection_expression >["property_name"]. So, effectively,

```
c.name
```

is same as

```
c["name"]
```

The syntax < collection_expression >["property_name"] allows one to derefence properties which might have non-identifier characters like 'my value' (space between my and value), or keywords like 'Value', 'Select' etc.

Hence,

```
SELECT C["Value"] 
FROM C
```

will work in your case.